# pattern for input type="text" with min and max number

Tags: html, regex, validation

how to write pattern for input type="text" (it can't be number and the validation can't be with JS) that allow me to enter only numbers, min:1 and max:5000?

```html
    <input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required pattern=""/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go - not an input with `type="number"` and no JS:

```
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required="required"
 pattern="(5000|([1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[1-9])"/>
```

The basic pattern is to match 5000 or 4-digit number or 3-digit number or 2-digit number or non-zero 1-digit number.

If you can accept 0, the pattern can be even simpler:

```
(5000|([1-4]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?))
```

Comment: @light  how about if I want a min=0 and max=24 ?

Answer (score -4):

You can use the predefined `min` and `max` attribute for `input type="number"` as follows,

```
<input type="number" min=0 max=10>
<input type="submit">
```

[**Here is an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/z0swuk3g/)

The error for incorrect input will be displayed when you try to submit the form

Comment: can still input any integer by typing. works only with ticker