# Input type="text" currency validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have an input type="text" that I transform into a currency value on the "keyup" event. In order to keep this functionality (works fine), the input type has to be set to "text". At the same time, I would like to have a minimum value of "100.00" set to it.
Any way I can accomplish this? Also, would I able to customize my jquery validation message to say "Minimum Amount $100.00"?

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required id="balance" name="balance" type="text" class="number" />
```

Comment: Can you share your attempts? You're asking us to add a minimum and an error message but it isn't clear what you've already tried, nor what is giving you trouble, as your code doesn't include anything related to minimums nor error messages.

Comment: @TylerRoper, I've tried to use a pattern as stated here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786775/pattern-for-input-type-text-with-min-and-max-number, but it does not recognize the decimal points.

Comment: I was about to make a comment about how modifying the user's input on `keyup` is bad design because it interferes with stuff like backspacing, but you've handled this remarkably well. My only complaint from a UI perspective is let's say I typed `1.00` but I meant `2.00`, so I go to the start to try and delete the one, but because your formatter kicks in, it sends my cursor position to the end and I end up with `0.02` - not what I wanted at all. There's no easy solution to this case, though...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, yep not a whole of wiggle room there. Howerver, in my opinion, the end result justify the little inconvenience of using the backspace key or highlighting the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this property in your input filed: `minlength="5"`

`<input required id="balance" name="balance" type="text" class="number" minlength="5" />`

And in your JS code you can add a 'if' statement to check that this input contain at least 5 char.

Furthermore you can add the same 'if' statement in your back-end to check it again.

Comment: I have tried that route and in the worse case scenario I can go into that direction. I was just trying to use the Jquery Validation as everything else on the page. Thanks for your perspective though. I appreciate.

Comment: Ok, then I guess this link can be usefull for your need [https://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/](https://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/)

Answer (score 0):

A snippet created using the `type="number"` instead of `type="text"` on the `input` still allows the jQuery functionality to work.

The validation message is HTML5 and not jQuery as you did not provide that code. I did the following:

1. Changed to `type="number"`
2. Added `min="100"`
3. Added `step="0.01"` to handle currency stepping

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Text input (original): <input required id="balance" name="balance" class="number" type="text" /><br /> 
  Number input: <input required id="balance" name="balance" class="number" type="number" min="100" max="99999" step="0.01" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
  <small>Enter less than 100 and press 'submit' to see validations.</small>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I appreciate. It does solve my problem in part. The type="number" only allows 5 digits and my users can enter a much higher number than what it allows. Any way I can solve that part of the problem?

Comment: Add a `max="99999"` to the input to limit the number. This is a validation check and not an input check, so the user needs to submit the form.

Comment: On second look, I'm confused on your desired result: do you want to limit it to 5 digits?

Comment: I wanted to allow the user to enter 999,999,999,999.00 and that seems to be a daunting task using the type number. So, I've left as text and checked the value on a function. Thanks!

Comment: The type="number" is not limiting it to 5 digits, but the RegEx you provided in your function is adding a comma (,) which is not a valid character in a number input and therefore, clears it out after enter the sixth digit: 1,234.56

Comment: I would look into a jQuery Input Mask plugin for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input.
I've ended up keeping the input type="text" for the number of digits users can type in and called a function to check the input value against the 100.

```
function checkAmount() {  
var valueBalance = $("#balance").val();
var valueNumberBalance = parseFloat((valueBalance).replace(/[^\d\.]/, ''));

if (valueNumberBalance < 100) {     
    $("#balance").get(0).setCustomValidity("Minimum Amount of $100.00");
}
else {
    $("#balance").get(0).setCustomValidity("");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can try to currency validation using regex

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <b>Premium :*</b><br>
            <p><input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = ''" name="premium" id="premium" valideAtt="currency" title="Premium" onblur="defaultValidation(this)"></p>
            <span id="er_premium" style="display: block; width:100%; float: left;"></span>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            var REG_CURRENCY = /(?=.*\d)^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

            function defaultValidation(src){
                var getAttributeValue=src.attributes.valideAtt.value;

                if(getAttributeValue=="currency"){
                    if(!src.value.match(REG_CURRENCY)){
                        $("#"+src.id).addClass("invalid");
                        $("#er_"+src.id).html("<span style=\"color:red\">Please Enter Valide currency Value.<\span>");
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        $("#er_"+src.id).html("");  
                        return true;
                    }
                }           
            }
<script>
```