# How to place a minlength on an input of type=text?

Tags: html, attributes

Do you know how to put a minlength on an input of type text?

I tried:

```
minlength="2"

min="2"

pattern=".{2,}"

pattern="^.{2,}$"
```

For information, this my input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname" pattern="^.{2,}$" >
```

I tried on Chrome and it doesn't work. But it is working on Firefox. So I will try to search on this side.

Comment: `pattern=".{2,}"   required` these attributes should do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pattern for input type="text" with min and max number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786775/pattern-for-input-type-text-with-min-and-max-number)

Comment: @NicolasMaties : i tried with required but it is the same result.

Comment: @midnightgamer i read this post but it won't work in my case, Because the text can be very long so i can put all the length in the pattern.

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: @cнŝdk it's a form and if the input is less than 2 characters, it must not submit the form.

Comment: @C.Ramp what is your browser you are testing this HTML on?

Comment: @Martin I use Chrome

Comment: are you sure you are uploading the file to overwrite the current one? Are you sure that you are force refreshing the page in the browser? 2 of the 4 methods you post will absolutely work in Chrome (any version). So the issue seems like your page is not being updated or you have something else going on (such as javascript or syntax errors outside of the shown code)

Comment: @Martin I'm sure to refresh my page. I cleared the cache. i change my code to be sure that i am on the good page. and i see my changes.

Comment: Is your page online? Can I see a link to it?

Comment: @Martin it's not online. I don't know how to show you.

Comment: @C.Ramp drop it in https://pastebin.com/ and let me know the URL. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `minlength` is absolutely correct:

```
minlength="2"
```

**Working Example:**

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" minlength="2" placeholder="Type here..." required />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can see that if you try to submit the form before you have entered a valid value into the text input, the form will not submit and the browser will report an error message.

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength

Comment: I'd like to add that without the `required` attribute the `minlength` **wont have an effect IF the input is left EMPTY**

Comment: i put "required" but the result is the same

Comment: If you run the code snippet above, you'll see that the `<input>` has a translucent red dashed line around it when it contains `0` or `1` characters, indicating that the value entered is invalid. When it has `2` or more characters entered the value is then recognised as valid.

Comment: @Rounin I see, that's why i post this question. It is because I don't have this behaviour in my site.

Comment: Have you run your markup through a validator like: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ ?

Comment: @Rounin I forgot to do this. So i did it but i don't have errors.

Comment: @C.Ramp does the code snippet in Rounin's answer work correctly for you on your browser?

Comment: @Martin when i do a new page with Rounin's code, it works. but put in my code, it doesn't work.

Comment: @C.Ramp then you need to find what's up with your page -- is there Javascript on it? I/we can't help much more, but the answer to the question you asked is definitely here ^^ . Why that answer isn't working in this case is impossible to judge without seeing more code evidence. Sorry.